# Can you specify per program how Internet Explorer handles hyperlinks?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

[image]

Is there a way to configure Internet Explorer's "Open links from other programs in:" option per program?

I'm looking for a way to allow different programs to act differently when clicking hyperlinks. For example, if I click a hyperlink in Microsoft Outlook I'd prefer it to open a new tab in the current window (option 2) but if I click a link out of an instant messenger program I'd prefer it to open in the current tab or window (option 3). Version wise I'm looking for a way to do it with IE 8+.